# get ALL tweets of a user using python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm doing a project for which I need to crawl ALL the tweets of a particular user. But as of now I'm able to crawl only the 3240 most recent tweets. Is there no way I can download all the tweets of a user?

Comment: Use the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API `statuses/user_timeline` [endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) can only retrieve up to 3,200 of a user's most recent tweets, as you've found:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether include_rts is set to false when requesting this resource.

To get complete historical data for a specific user, you'd have to go through a data broker.  The big one is [Gnip](http://www.gnip.com), which is cost prohibitive for most.  Another alternative is [Sifter](http://sifter.texifter.com/), which is $30 per 100,000 tweets; however, there is a $20 per/day of history cost in addition to volume, so, depending on how far back a user's tweets go, this could also be cost prohibitive.